# Setting TTL on RabbitMQ queue using Servicestack

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, servicestack, ttl

[I have read](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) that it is possible to set a time to live (TTL) on a RabbitMQ (per queue) so that a message will be wiped from the queue by the RabbitMQ server if the TTL expires, and that the server will guarantee that messages that have an expired TTL will not be processed.

I am using [service stack to connect to various rabbitMq's](http://docs.servicestack.net/rabbit-mq); specifically I am using it to act as a facade over the RPC functionality rabbitMQ provides, and it does work quite well.

I am unable to find any information (and also looking at the code - support) for setting the queue's TTL when it is declared. As far as I can see, the creation of the queue is buried in the Service Stack implementation - which abstracts a lot of the queue details to provide a simplified service abstraction regardless of the transport layer.

Is it possible to do this (to set a TTL on the rabbit MQ using service stack) - or will it be possible to do this in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a filter which will let you customize what options Rabbit MQ Queue's and topics get created with which you can specify with the new `CreateQueueFilter`, e.g:

```
container.Register<IMessageService>(c => 
    new RabbitMqServer(ConnectionString)
    {
        CreateQueueFilter = (queueName, args) =>
        {
            if (queueName == QueueNames<MyRequest>.In)
            {
                args["x-message-ttl"] = 60000;
            }
        }
    });
```

This change is available from v4.5.7+ that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: You are my hero. Seriously! Thanks!